# How to multiply an indefinite amount of rows by the same number?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

Basically just trying to create a formula in excel to calculate my university WAM. The formula is 
- Sum of (subject credit * mark) / sum of (subject credit)

So if I have a column of my marks (B2:B25) how do I then multiply each value in the array by The subject credit.
And then divide that answer by the amount of values there are in the array * subject credit.

So B26 will be the WAM

I am completely new to excel/vba so please excuse the simplicity of the question. If the solution requires programming I'm comfortable with that.

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Can you [edit] your question with some sample data and the expected result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use SUMPRODUCT():

```
=SUMPRODUCT(A2:A25,B2:B25)/SUM(A2:A25)
```

Where A2:A25 are the subject credits and B2:B25 are the marks.

Comment: Yeah not to sure you need a sumproduct, just go sum(range 1 * range 2)/  sum (range 3).